# how to change appearance of a user control after it is clicked

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I'm a beginner program designer so please go easy on me!

I want to change the appearance of my user control when the click event fires. It's a custom user control designed to show a 'Logged In' status that is green or a 'Logged out' status that is red. I need the stroke and fill to change from red to green when clicked and vice versa, as along with either a red cross icon or green tick icon.

I can do it manually in the xaml but not sure how to make it fire in the code behind?

Answer (score 1):

Preferred solution is to separate visuals from logic. In this case, create appropriate state for your control in xaml using [visual state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstate.aspx), and change your control's state with [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.gotostate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

on event handler(if u know what it is), create the instance of your usercontrol and change the property.

Comment: @Emil Why you think it doesn't provide answer? Did you tried whatever he suggested? You cannot demotivate any one who is trying to help someone, by writing such comments.